# How do I assign sequential values over a jQuery collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like a bonehead: I want to assign `index=i` to each LI I have selected, with i incrementing. It appears to assign them all at once though, and they all get `index=1`. Thoughts?

```
$("#window ul li").each(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $(this).attr("index", i);
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback function that you pass into each is given the zero-based index in the collection as the first argument.

```
$("#window ul li").each(function(i){
    $(this).attr("index", i+1);
});
```

So if you want your index to start with 1, add 1.

Comment: Wow; so it takes care of the iterator for you... Who knew. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because `each` executes the lambda function **for each** element **separately** and in each call you set the `i=1`. You can declare and inicialize the `i` before calling `each`.

```
var i = 1;
$("#window ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("index", i);
    i++;
});
```

**Edit**: But Mario's solution is much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 1;
$("#window ul li").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("index", i);
    i++;
});
```

This should work as well.